# Rhino Mock Expect.Call() actually calls the method not only create an expectation

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks

I want to test if a method has been called in the test.

My problem is that when I want to create the expectations it is not working as I thought. The next line actually runs the method, not only create an expectation:

```
Expect.Call(() => mockedService.MethodThatIExpectToRun(params));
```

There is another way:

```
mockedService.Expect((s=> s.MethodThatIExpectToRun(params)));
```

But this also actually runs the method, not only creates an expectation to be fulfilled by the test.

And this line that asserts if the method was not called also actually calls the method, not only checks whether it was called.

```
mockedService.AssertWasCalled(s=> s.MethodThatIExpectToRun((params)));
```

additional info:
`MethodThatIExpectToRun` returns `void`

For prgmtc's comment:

```
IService mockedService = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<Service>(mockedRepository_1, ..., mockedRepository_n);
```

Comment: What's the runtime type of mockedService? Is it a dynamic mock object created by RhinoMocks? Are you mocking an interface or a concrete class?

Comment: It is a partialMock. I needed to pass to it some mocked repository and I needed to stub some of the methods of the service class. I refresh the question also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you have `PartialMock` that's calling the real method when setting a `Stub` or `Expect`, it means the `virtual` keyword is missing on the method.

Make sure `Service.MethodThatIExpectToRun` is `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

A more general (although perhaps less useful) remark: Partial mocks can point to a design smell of the code under test. If you only want to provide expectations for a part of a class, then perhaps that class has too many responsibilities and should be split into multiple classes? That way you can cleanly isolate responsibilities/collaborators and have no need for the partialmock construct. If you mock (not partial mock) an interface or virtual member of a concrete class the call won't go through to the real implementation.

For example:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Real object: ");
        new Foo().Bar();

        Console.WriteLine("Mocked object: ");
        var aFoo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<Foo>();
        aFoo.Expect(f => f.Bar());

        aFoo.Bar();

        ...

        public class Foo
        {
            public virtual void Bar()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("REAL IMPLEMENTATION");
            }
        }
```

Outputs:

```
Real object: 
REAL IMPLEMENTATION
Mocked object:
```

Comment: "A partial mock will call the method defined on the class unless you define an expectation for that method." So if you define it should not call the original implementation.

Comment: Thank your for your support but I found out that my method was not marked as virtual and it was the problem.

Comment: The last line you're referring to "(Be aware, though, that once all the expectations for a method are settled, the method will be routed back to the implementation)" is actually saying that if you setup an expectation for a single call and two calls take place, the second call will go to the actual implementation, rather than the mocked one..

Comment: My bad, I interpreted the documentation wrong (and obivously did not test it for myself). The point of partialmocks pointing to possible design issues remains however.